# Getting error when trying to add user as a Tester on a Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I have an App on developers.facebook.com portal where I have set up some users as administrator and others as tester roles. Now, I am trying to add a new user as a tester role but I get the following error:

[image: Getting error when adding a tester user]

Not long time ago, I could add users with tester roles with no problem but I can't now. Has something changed on Facebook's portal or is there something wrong on my App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did just try now and finally managed to add the user as a tester on that App! No change has been made on the App so I wonder something has been fixed on Facebook developers portal.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and rather than finding a proper solution, flipped the app to Live and added users that way.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to flip the app to Live as it's for the QA environment of the App and I just wanted to add as a tester a new QA tester user.